# Redirect all incoming traffic from a secondary public IP to an internal IP address using iptables

Tags: iptables

I'm currently trying to figure out how I can forward traffic from a secondary public IP address of my dedicated server to an internal IP of my network using iptables in order to make e.g. webservers and the like visible from outside.

My setup is a dedicated server containing three virtual machines which form a "private LAN". The connection between those is established and the virtual machines can connect to the internet through a bridge between the isolated LAN and the physical server. Allowing **outgoing** traffic is established using the following rule (LAN: 192.168.x.x, Example Public Address: 8.8.8.8):

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.101 -j SNAT --to-source 8.8.8.8
```

This works fine - if I open an internet browser and go to whatismyip.com it will now no longer show the server's main IP address, but instead it will show the secondary IP just the way it's supposed to do.

However, now I'd love to do the other way around and install e.g. a web server on one of the virtual machines and make it available to the public through my secondary IP. I was searching for the answer and found I'm supposed to add a PREROUTING rule in order to accomplish this, thus I tried the following:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 8.8.8.8 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.101
```

Connecting to port 80 of the public IP will time out, though. It seems like I'm still missing something or there's a mistake in the way I do the rules.

**Please note:** Rather than opening only a specific port, I'd like to forward all incoming traffic on that specific IP to the virtual machine and handle security over there.

Any advice would be appreciated - perhaps I'm just missing something minor.

Comment: What is default gateway on server with IP 192.168.1.101?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You will need a combination of DNAT and SNAT, and you need ip_forwarding active.

First, check ip_forwarding:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

If it is 1 (enabled), go ahead. If not, you will have to put  `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` on `/etc/sysctl.conf` and run `sysctl -p`.

The first rule is DNAT (assume `8.8.8.8` as the external IP and `192.168.0.10` as the internal):

```
iptables -t nat -A  PREROUTING -d 8.8.8.8 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.10
```

When a external system (e.g. `200.100.50.25`) sends a packet reaching 8.8.8.8 will have the `DESTINATION` changed to `192.168.0.10`, and sent away. But the source will be `200.100.50.25`, the packet will be processed and the response packet can:

1. Be dropped by 192.168.0.10 that may not know how to route it. Not desirable.
2. Be sent by 192.168.0.10 to the default gateway and to internet. As soon as it reaches `200.100.50.25`, this system will had never heard of `192.168.0.10` and will drop the packet. Not good.
3. Be dropped on the first hop, as `192.168.0.10` is a private address and not routeable on Internet.

To solve this, you need the second rule, SNAT:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.10 -j SNAT --to-source 8.8.8.8
```

With this rule, every packet that comes from `192.168.0.10` will have the source changed to `8.8.8.8` and sent away.

The collateral effect is that every log on `192.168.0.10` will show `8.8.8.8` as the client, not the real client. Tracking abusers will be a little harder.

Comment: Oh it's finally working. Many thanks for the AWESOME explanation and solution to my problem!!

Comment: The SNAT rule would only be needed for point 1, which could be solved by configuring the 192.168.0.10 to have the machine that "owns" 8.8.8.8 to be the default router.  The DNAT rule implies that return packets will also be translated back so points 2 and 3 are not relevant.

Comment: Is there a way to make this rule generic so that outgoing traffic on port 80 from any client will be redirected?

Comment: This will not work, you'll get a "Bad argument `1.2.3.4'". There is a syntax error, parameters should be --to-source and --to-destinations with double tract --

Comment: I'm trying this commands but after this, the server is not reachable anymore and won't forward anything until I restart iptables

Comment: You can also use MASQUERADE for the second rule, which means you do not have to specify the IP to use as the sender of the outgoing packet:

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE`